# Making A Global File Path

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, global-variables, filepath

Goal: Use open function to allow user to run commands on whichever file they choose to open across multiple functions(path is in a public function).

This is the initial function that prompts the user to select a file. That file path is saved in the variable "path". I made the function public with the intention of using "path" in multiple areas(globalization).

```
Public Function OpenFile1() As String
    On Error GoTo Trap

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .Title = "Open Sterling Shipment History" 'Name for file
        .Filters.Clear
        .ButtonName = " Open "
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
    End With

    If fd.Show <> 0 Then OpenFile1 = fd.SelectedItems(1)

Leave:
    Set fd = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function

Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
    Dim path As String
path = OpenFile1() 'Calls in file

If path <> vbNullString Then Debug.Print path
Workbooks.Open (path)


'rename the path variable for each function
'so that I can call in different files with that name
End Function
```

This is an excerpt of the second function that attempts to call the file path from the variable "path", use it to open the workbook and alter the workbook.

```
Sub Shipment_History()
Call OpenFile1
Dim sshist As Workbook
Set sshist = Workbooks.Open(path)
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

I also tried:

```
  Sub Shipment_History()
  Call OpenFile1
  Workbooks.Open(path)
```

My issue is it isn't allowing me to open "path".

The error states

> "Run-time error '1004': Sorry, we couldn't find. Is it possible it was
>   moved, renamed or deleted?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function returns a string (path) and it is publicly available, you dont need a public variable to store the path.

Declare the path variable locally and set it's value to the value (path) returned from the function:

```
Sub Shipment_History()

    Dim path as string
    path = OpenFile1()

    If path <> vbNullString Then Workbooks.Open(path)
End Sub
```

p.s. Remove everything after `Resume Leave` except the `End Function` statement.

Comment: Cool beans thanks, this works. I have one question. Do you know how I would navigate to the open spreadsheet? I tried using WIndows(path).Activate, however it states "subscript out of range", is it not calling the file path?

Comment: You need to set a reference to the workbook and call its `Activate` method. `Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path)`

Comment: Is the only way to use the wb.activate in multiple functions just defining each time? Or is there a better way without repetition?

Comment: There's no real straightforward answer to this question as it mostly depends on the design of your application. If you need that reference in many places, consider making it public and set it when you open the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

path must be declared outside any Function or Subscript as a public String, the function doesnt need to be public, its the variable.

Try this on a module:

```
Public path As String

Function setPathValue(ByVal dataPassed As String)
    path = dataPassed
End Function

Sub givePathVal()
    setPathValue ("This is path value")
End Sub

Sub showPathVal()
    MsgBox path
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Your module works, however my code is now having the issue of ambiguous code. The issue with that is I only define it in one section( an isolated module). Do you have any idea on how to clear this ? (apologies about the compounded question)

Comment: Can you post the subscript where you get the ambiguous code error?